# simple program doesn't work with negative array numbers

Tags: c, max

I just started to learn C language. By now I have very basic knowledge. At the moment I am coding some very simple programs from given exercises by my University.

Current exercise I have is: *Write a program that finds two largest elements in n element array (2 ≤ n ≤ 10) and outputs sum of those two elements.*

The problem is that my written code works only with positive array numbers and doesn't work with negative numbers.

Current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int seka[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //array in lithuanian = seka
    int k; //variable to determine array size
    int m = seka[0];
    int n = seka[0];
    int y = 0;

    scanf ("%d",&k);
    for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i){
        scanf ("%d",&seka[i]);
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < k; ++j){
        if (seka[j] > m)
            m = seka[j];
    }

    for(int o = 0; o < k; ++o){
        if (seka[o] == m)
            y = y + 1;
    }

    if(y >= 2){
        n = m;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int l = 0; l < k; ++l){
            if(seka[l] != m)
                if (seka[l] > n)
                    n = seka[l];
        }
    }

    printf ("%d", m + n);
    return 0;
}
```

Input used:

```
5
4 9 5 6 3
```

Output got:

```
15
```

But if input has negative numbers:

```
6
-5 -8 -6 -2 -5 -8
```

Output is:

```
0
```

I know that this is not the most efficient approach for given problem, but I am still learning and I hope that you will help me finding the root of the issue.

**Fixed my code with your help, now works like it should.**

**Fixed code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int seka[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //array in lithuanian = seka
    int k; //variable to determine array size
    int y = 0;

    scanf ("%d",&k);
    for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i){
      scanf ("%d",&seka[i]);
    }
    int m = seka[0];
    for(int j = 1; j < k; ++j){
        if (seka[j] > m)
        m = seka[j];
    }

    for(int o = 0; o < k; ++o){
        if (seka[o] == m)
        y = y + 1;
    }

    int n;

    for(int l = 0; l < k; ++l){
        if(seka[l] != m)
        if (seka[l] < n)
        n = seka[l];
    }

    if(y >= 2){
        n = m;
    }
    else
    {   
        for(int l = 0; l < k; ++l){
        if(seka[l] != m)
        if (seka[l] > n)
        n = seka[l];
    }
    }

    printf ("%d", m + n);
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `int m = seka[0]; int n = seka[0];` should be defined *after* the array data has been read.

Comment: @hedgie I don't think he means negative indexes, he means negative values in the array.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You update the max value with

```
for(int j = 0; j < k; ++j){
  if (seka[j] > m)
      m = seka[j];
}
```

but you initialize it with

```
 m = seka[0];
```

The problem is that `seka[0]` has not been set by the user, yet, so its value is 0. That's Why the maximum value cannot be less than 0.

---

In order to fix it, just initialize the maximum with the first element of the array, but **after** the user input. Then loop starting from index 1:

```
m = seka[0];
for(int j = 1; j < k; ++j){
    if (seka[j] > m)
        m = seka[j];
}
```